# What Type are UI Images in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, types

I'm new to using UI in Unity and I can't seem to figure out what type UI Images are. Essentially I want a SerializedField so I can set the Images in the editor then change them through Code.

```
public Image Image1, Image2, Image3;
```

I want to do something like this and I can't seem to find the name for the type anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried to ask the Unity API ... ? -> [UnityEngine.UI.Image](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@2.0/api/UnityEngine.UI.Image.html) takes 5 seconds to google this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you forgot to add using "UnityEngine.UI" ?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using UnityEngine.UI; // this things. :)

public class Something: MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image image1;
    public Image image2;
    public Image image3;

    private void Start()
    {
        
    }
}
```